# Flex 3 DataGrid Component Losing Focus

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm running into problems getting the focus to work on my custom datagrid.  It is a subclass of MDataGrid which can be found [here](http://reusable-fx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/com/iwobanas/controls/MDataGrid.html).

My problems is, that every other mouse click on inline components actually focuses on the component.  The other clicks seem to automatically lose focus to something else, and I can't seem to figure out what is going on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

--Charly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<controls:MDataGrid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                xmlns:controls="com.iwobanas.controls.*" 
                xmlns:dgc="com.iwobanas.controls.dataGridClasses.*"
                dataProvider="{locator.vendorInvoices}"
                editable="true">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import model.PayablesLocator;

        [Bindable] private var locator:PayablesLocator = PayablesLocator.getInstance();
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<controls:columns>

    <dgc:MDataGridColumn dataField="loadNumber" 
                         headerText="Load"
                         editable="false"/>

    <dgc:MDataGridColumn dataField="carrierName" 
                         headerText="Carrier"
                         editable="false"/>

    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Vendor Invoice #"
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="vendorInvoiceNumber">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                         implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer, mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent">                      

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
                            import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
                            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                            private var _listData:DataGridListData;
                            [Bindable] public var vendorInvoiceNumber:String;

                            // Implements mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent
                            override public function drawFocus(draw:Boolean):void {
                                invoiceNumberInput.setFocus();
                            }

                            // Implements mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer
                            override public function get data():Object {
                                return super.data;
                            }   

                            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                                super.data = value;
                                invoiceNumberInput.text = data.vendorInvoiceNumber
                            }

                            public function get listData():BaseListData {
                                return _listData;
                            }   

                            public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void {
                                _listData = DataGridListData(value);
                            }

                            private function onChange(event:Event):void {
                                data.vendorInvoiceNumber = invoiceNumberInput.text;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>

                    <mx:TextInput id="invoiceNumberInput"
                                  width="95%"
                                  change="onChange(event)"/>                        
                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Vendor Invoice Date"
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="vendorInvoiceDate">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                         implements="mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent">                       

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[                               
                            import mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent;

                            [Bindable] public var vendorInvoiceDate:Date;

                            // Implements mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent
                            override public function drawFocus(draw:Boolean):void {
                                vendorInvoiceDateInput.setFocus();
                            }

                            protected function onChange(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void {
                                data.vendorInvoiceDate = event.newDate;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>

                    <mx:DateField id="vendorInvoiceDateInput"
                                  width="95%"
                                  editable="true"
                                  change="onChange(event)"/>                        
                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

    <mx:DataGridColumn editorDataField="isSelected"
                       headerText="Select"
                       rendererIsEditor="true">         
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>

                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                         implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer,mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent">

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import controller.PayablesController;

                            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
                            import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;

                            private var control:PayablesController = PayablesController.getInstance();

                            private var _listData:DataGridListData;
                            [Bindable] public var isSelected:Boolean;

                            override public function drawFocus(draw:Boolean):void {
                                selectionCheckBox.setFocus();
                            }

                            override public function get data():Object {
                                return super.data;

                            }   

                            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                                super.data = value;
                                selectionCheckBox.selected = data.isSelected
                            }

                            public function get listData():BaseListData {
                                return _listData;
                            }   

                            public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void {
                                _listData = DataGridListData(value);
                            }

                            protected function onChange(event:Event):void {
                                data.isSelected = selectionCheckBox.selected;
                                control.updateBatchSelections();
                            }                               
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>  

                    <mx:CheckBox id="selectionCheckBox" change="onChange(event)"/>

                </mx:HBox>

            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

</controls:columns>
```